# It fails to define a const_iterator from it's counterpart iterator

Tags: c++, const-iterator

I am extending stl container with a self defined container so as to provide more flexible control on the operations of the elements

```
class MyContainer;

template <typename T> class myiterator :public iterator<bidirectional_iterator_tag, T>
{
  friend class MyContainer;
  private:
    T *pointer;

    myiterator(T *pt):pointer(pt) {}

  public:
    T& operator*() {return (*pointer);}

    const myiterator<T>& operator++()
    {
      pointer->current_iterator++;
       return *this;
    }

    bool isEnd(void) const
    {
      return pointer->current_iterator == pointer->data.end();
    }
  };

class MyContainer
{
  friend class myiterator<MyContainer>;
  public:
    typedef myiterator<MyContainer> iterator;
    typedef myiterator<MyContainer const> const_iterator;

  private:
    map<int, int> data;
    map<int, int>::const_iterator current_iterator;

  public:
    MyContainer() {current_iterator = data.begin(); }

    void addDataPair(int key, int value) {data[key] = value;}

    int first() const {return (*current_iterator).first;}
    int second() const {return (*current_iterator).second;}

    iterator begin() 
    {
      current_iterator = data.begin();
      return iterator(this);
    }

    const_iterator begin() const
    {
      return const_iterator(this);
    }
  };
```

This code run ok, if I use iterator as follow

```
MyContainer h;

h.addDataPair(1, 1);
h.addDataPair(2, 2);
h.addDataPair(3, 3);

for (MyContainer::iterator it=h.begin(); !it.isEnd(); ++it)
{
  cout << (*it).first() << " " << (*it).second() << endl;
}
```

But it won't compile if I change iterator to const_iterator. I read some article, which mention that to define constant iterator, we simply replace the value_type from X to X const, that's how I did in my code. But I soon find that it might won't work in my case because the reference returned by an iterator is the container itself in my case. I don't know then how to make the const_iterator work without duplicate the coding.

In addition, my iterator is derived from std::iterator but I found that I cannot override 
the constructor for my iterator. Is that any way that I can pass more than one parameters into my iterator besides the T *pt ? Thanks.

Comment: This is a bit odd.  MyContainer appears to be both a container and an iterator.

Comment: I know :) Because I don't want the code to modify the map<int, int>'s element directly so I write a wrapper to control that while they are trying to access the map data with operator[], operator++ , etc. I was going to inherit std::map to do so but seems that it is not recommended to do so because of the virtual destructor. Anyway, this is the only way I can think of to keep the interface as close as the map and add some controls.

Comment: What are you wanting that a const map wouldn't provide?

Comment: Do you want there to be any difference between a const_iterator and an iterator of your container?

Comment: Hi Vaughn, since the data stored in the map is really sensitive and I don't want them to be changed for some case, so I need a const_iterator in that siutation.

Comment: Typically if you don't want the data to be changed, you would pass a const reference or a const iterator of a standard container, and creating your own wrapper wouldn't be necessary.  I'm trying to understand what is special about your situation that makes the wrapper necessary.

Answer (score 1):

First problem:

If you change this:

```
for (MyContainer::iterator it=h.begin(); !it.isEnd(); ++it)
```

to

```
for (MyContainer::const_iterator it=h.begin(); !it.isEnd(); ++it)
```

then you get a non-const `iterator` from `begin()` and `end()` and try to initialize a `const_iterator` from it, but that's a different type and your `my_iterator` template doesn't have a constructor that allows construction from a different type.

You can fix that by adding:

```
template<typename> friend class myiterator;

template<typename T2>
  myiterator(myiterator<T2> const& i) : pointer(i.pointer) { }
```

You should also make `operator*` const (it doesn't alter the iterator to dereference it.)

But there's still a bigger problem, a `const_iterator` points to a `const MyContainer`, but `const_iterator::operator++` needs to alter that object, which it can't because it's const.  So you can't increment your `const_iterator` i.e. can't use it to iterate! You might want to rethink that design.